# TikZ calc doesn't accept coordinates defined in a \newcommand like (x,y) (with parenteses)

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

I've defined a new command like `\newcommand{\with}{(1,1)}` because I'd like to make a `tikzpicture` with a "parametrical" starting point and built all the other coordinates from there.

But if it this new command used in `calc`ulated coordinates it gives the error:

> ! File ended while scanning use
>   of \tikz@cc@parse@factor.

while, normally, it works. Why?

The same `\newcommand` without parentheses (adding them afterwards) always works.

```
\documentclass[tikz, preview=true]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\without}{1,2}
\newcommand{\with}{(1,1)}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (a) at (\without) {Without calc and command without parentheses: this works};
        \node (b) at \with {Without calc and command with parentheses: this works too};
        \node (c) at ($(\without)-(0,2)$) {With calc and command without parentheses: this works};
        \node (d) at ($\with-(0,2)$) {With calc and command with parentheses: this doesn't work};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess that `$` triggers looking for `(`, but without expanding macros and takes different paths depending on whether `(` is seen. Indeed `\node (d) at \expandafter(\expandafter$\with-(0,2)$)` works.

Comment: It might be easier just to use \coordinate (without) at (1,2); etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo But that doesn't avoid having to put the parenteses here: `\node (c) at ($(without)-(0,2)$)...` and they are necessary also here: `\node (b) at (with)...`. Are there advantages in using `\coordinate`?

Comment: As opposed to using `\expandafter(\expandafter$` ?  Think of (...) as being part of the name, like \... is part of a macro name.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, I intended w.r.t. `\newcommand{\with}{(1,1)}`. I think egreg used `\expandafter(\expandafter$` only to show the reason of the error, not as a possible solution :)

Comment: Would it make a difference to know that coordinate (with) is actually stored as macro \csname pgf@sh@nt@with\endcsname ?

Comment: @JohnKormylo ...hence it's more elegant but it's the same thing... :)

Comment: @JohnKormylo However, I've used `\coordinate`, eventually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the parenthesis problem egreg is right, the use of `$` makes `tikz` try to parse coordinates, that means looking for `(` and `)`, it also Looks for the math operators `+` and `-` between `)` and `(`, that's why `\expandafter` works.

About what you wish to do, which is create key coordinates from which your drawing will depend on. You can use instead of a command, a style, e.g. `create key coordinates`, with `insert path={(x,y) coordinate (a) ...}`, then use it as first thing in the drawing:

```
\path[create key coordinates];
```

Then you can create as many key coordinates as you wish with one single style.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{%
    create key coordinates/.style={%
        insert path={(1,1) coordinate (a)
                     %make more coordinates if you wish...
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[create key coordinates];
        \node[below=5cm] at (a) {This is using the key coordinate `a'};
        \draw (0,0) -- ($(a)-(7/2,3*8)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```